# DAO null in spring bean class with xml config

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm trying to inject the uploadDao in the bean DemoHandler (XML below). But as expected it is Null. The question is how do I inject the DAO correctly.

Right now, there is a method call from WebUploadServiceImpl to DemoHandler and I can add 1 more parameter and send the value I need from uploadDao, but then that method is reused for multiple java classes and all those methods need to be refactored and that new param will not be relevant to the other classes.

Is there a way to get uploadDao to inject in DemoHandler? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Spring XML:

```
<bean id="wuService" class="com.abcd.service.WebUploadServiceImpl">
        <property name="uploadDao" ref="uploadDao" />
        <property name="webHandlers">
            <set>
                <bean class="com.abcd.service.handler.DemoHandler" />
            </set>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Code:

```
public class DemoHandler {

private UploadDao uploadDao;

   public List handleM(...) {
        ...
        Period period = uploadDao.anyMethod(..); --- Null here
   }    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring your spring.xml to set a property named `uploadDao` just in your bean `DemoHandler`? Take a look at your WebUploadServiceImpl and copy how `uploadDao`is injected and replicate it in your `DemoHandler`(I don't know if you have an @autowired or just a set method)

Comment: @RubioRic I edited the spring xml to be more clear. The DemoHandler bean is declared within the WebUploadServiceImpl bean (property). Hope the XML is clear now

Comment: Eh, I already got that point in your first version. Do you know that you can set properties in those "inner" beans, don`t you? https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-inner-bean-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DemoHandler` needs to set a dao, why don't you do something like this ...

```
<bean id="uploadDao" class="whatever.dao.UploadDaoImpl"/>

<bean id="wuService" class="com.abcd.service.WebUploadServiceImpl">
        <property name="uploadDao" ref="uploadDao" />
        <property name="webHandlers">
            <set>
                <bean class="com.abcd.service.handler.DemoHandler">
                    <property name="uploadDao" ref="uploadDao" />
                </bean>
            </set>
        </property>
</bean>
```

You just need to replicate the injection mechanism already used in `WebUploadServiceImpl`. You haven't shown that code, I don´t know if you use `@Autowired`, a set method or any other possibility.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Testing now. Thanks so much!